# Example of a ring $R$ and a prime $0\neq P\unlhd R$ such that $R_P$ is a field?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, localization

> Give an example of a commutative ring $R$ and a nonzero prime ideal $P\unlhd R$ such that $R_P$ is a field.

I can't seem to think of any examples. If anyone has ideas, I would also appreciate hints on how you found your example (maybe briefly outline your thought process?), and also your method of showing that the localization at that prime is indeed a field.

Comment: If i were you, I'd list out the examples that were *eliminated* when you worked. When a ring as simple as $F_2\times F_2$ is an example to your question, it looks kind of like you didn't think of any examples at all. I appreciate you may not have known how to see a localization of it, but if you *said so* it would look a lot better for you. As written the whole question *looks* like a problem-statement-question, which is bad.

Comment: I understand where you're coming from. The question is part of a problem I found on a list of past qualifying exams I've been working through. I asked to users to show their work in my post because I was genuinely interested in how people were thinking about this. I suppose I just got a bit lazy. Admittedly, looking back at my work, none of the examples I tried had zero divisors so if I had made a list, as you've suggested, before posting perhaps that is something I would have tried.

Comment: Yes, it's the best policy to help stave off closure votes for the reasons I outlined above.

Comment: That makes sense – I'll definitely keep it in mind for future posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that $R_{\mathfrak p}$ is a local ring with $\mathfrak p^e$ being the maximal ideal, so for $R_{\mathfrak p}$ to be a field, we must have $\mathfrak p^e = 0$, i.e. $\frac x 1 = 0$ for every $x \in \mathfrak p$, i.e. for every $x \in \mathfrak p$ there is $s \notin \mathfrak p$ such that $xs = 0$.

An example that comes to mind is $2 \times 3 = 0$ in $\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z$, so $R = \Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z$ and $\mathfrak p = \langle 2 + 6 \Bbb Z \rangle$, in which case $R_{\mathfrak p} \cong \Bbb F_2$, the field of $2$ elements.

Answer (score 2):

Such a prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ is necessarily a *minimal* prime ideal, , hence an *associated* prime ideal, i.e. if the ring $R$ is noetherian, $\mathfrak p=\operatorname{Ann}_R a$. If $a\notin \mathfrak p$, it is a unit in  $R_{\mathfrak p}$, so $\mathfrak pR_{\mathfrak p}=\{0\}$, which means   $R_{\mathfrak p}$ is a field.

*Example* :

Take $R=K[X,Y]/(XY)$, $\mathfrak p=(X)/(XY)$ is the annihilator of $Y+(XY)$, and 
$$k(\mathfrak p)\simeq K(Y).$$